# passing current timer's timing to the next page

Tags: javascript, html

How would i pass my current timer's timing into the next page?

Timer code

```
var expires = new Date();

expires.setSeconds(expires.getSeconds() + 60); // set timer to 60 seconds
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1);

function timer() {
    var timeDiff = expires - new Date();

    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:00";
        return;
    }

    var seconds = new Date(timeDiff).getSeconds();    
    var milliSeconds = (new Date(timeDiff).getMilliseconds()/10).toFixed(0);

    var seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds: seconds;
    var milliSeconds = milliSeconds < 10 ? "0" + milliSeconds: milliSeconds;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds + ":" + milliSeconds; // watch for spelling
}
```

I'm using

```
<h3 style="color: #ff0000; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%;font-weight:normal; font-family: robotolight;"> You have <div id="timer"></div> to complete the game!
```

in my html.

Is there a way to pass div id='timer'> into the next page?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use cookies or localStorage

Comment: localStorage.setItem('timer','timerpage1');
Is this the correct way to store the timer data?

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the page or loading a new page means reloading javascript since it is runs in the context of the current page.  There is good way to pass along javascript variables to a new page; it requires some form of data persistence.  Cookies and localStorage are two of the most common ways of persisting data client-side.

Client cookies are written to the browser cache and are transparent in HTTP headers.  LocalStorage is a newer mechanism but well supported, allowing up to 5MB of browser storage without passing in headers.

In your use case, instead of storing the timer it would probably make sense to store the timestamp when the timer was started.  That way it can be recalculated in the next page from this one static start value.

```
var timerStart;
var expireDate = new Date();

function displayTimer(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timerStart = timerStart || cookieTimer();
    val timeDiff = now - timerStart;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeDiff.toString();

    if(timeDiff > expireDate.getTime()) clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

val timerInterval = setInterval(displayTimer, 1);


// Using cookies
function cookieTimer(){

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1); 
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, expireDate) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expireDate.getTime());
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    var timerCookie = getCookie("timer");

    if(timerCookie !== "") return new Date(timerCookie).getTime());
    else {
        setCookie("timer", timerStart, expireDate);
        return new Date().getTime();  
    }
}



// Using localStorage
function localStorageTimer(){
    function setLocalStorageObject(key, obj, expireDate){
        obj.expires = expireDate.getTime();
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
    }

    function getLocalStorageObject(key){
        val item = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if(item) return JSON.parse(item);
        else return {};
    }

    var timerLocal = getLocalStorageObject("timer");
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    if(timerLocal && timerLocal.startTime && timerLocal.expires > now) return timerLocal.startTime;
    else {
        setLocalStorageObject("timer", { startTime: now });
        return now;
    }
}
```